# Java SWT asyncExec() freezes window on drag

Tags: java, window, swt, drag, freeze

I just had to write a test code for SWT threading test, and now stuck with Display.asyncExec() strange behavior.

```
addShellListener(new ShellAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e) {
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                    {
                        getLabel().setText(i+"");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    });
```

I just run loopped Runnable with asyncExec on shell start, which updates label value inside the shell every second, simulating timer. Everything is okay and ticking until i try to drag the window. The window freezes on dragging (including "ticking" label) and notification "The program is not responding" appears, with exiting possible only by Java VM process killing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand the use case, however in order to update the label every second, I recommend to wither spawn a background thread that triggers the label update every second or use timerExec() to  do the update and schedule another timerExec() for the next update():

**timerExec() variant**

```
private class LabelUpdater implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if( !label.isDisposed() ) {
      label.setText( ... );
      label.getParent().layout();
      display.timerExec( 1000, new LabelUpdater() );
    }
  }
}

shell.addListener( SWT.Activate, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    display.timerExec( 1000, new LabelUpdater() );
  }
} );
```

**Background Thread Variant**

```
private class LabelUpdater implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if( !label.isDisposed() ) {
      label.setText( ... );
      label.getParent().layout();
    }
  }
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
      display.asyncExec( new LabelUpdater() );
      try {
        Thread.sleep( 1000 );
      } catch( InterruptedException ignore ) {
        Thread.interrupted();
      }
    }
  }
};
Thread thread = new Thread( runnable );
thread.setDaemon( true );
thread.start();
```

Note that the `shell.isDisposed()` check isn't thread-safe, but doesn't harm in practice because the `LabelUpdater` has to check if the widgets it updates are still *alive* anyway. (see [here](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/15/safely-use-swt-display-asyncexec/) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: I wrote something simular to first example before, it's running well no blocking, **but** it has very strange behavior: it seems timeout vary from time to time and still doesn't reach 1 second interval, causing timer to tick faster and slower over time, although i don't know how it's possible!

Comment: timerExec() as well as asyncExec use facilities ofthe respective window system. Is is important for your use case to have an exact interal? How did you measure the time interval? Does the 'background thread varian' give better results?

Comment: Last night I found the reason for such a strange behavior: it was event driven and for some reason on Windows (possibly also on other platforms) shellActivated event occurs **every** time window 'activated': on opening, on switching between windows etc...

Comment: Hm, now that you mention it, the behavior is by design and works on all platforms. `Activate` and `Deactivate` events are triggered when shells are clicked, shown, hidden or brought to foreground/background. Under which conditions should the periodic label update be started and stopped?

Comment: I just remember writing a helper class to keep an SWT UI up-to-date that showed relative dates (like 'just now', 'an houg ago', etc). A Widget and a Runnable need to be given. The Runnable is then executed periodically as long as the Widget is not disposed. The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/rherrmann/43a9b3645694a2febef8 Maybe that solves your problem, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `Runnable` you give to `Display.asyncExec` is run in the SWT user interface thread. If you use `Thread.sleep` in this runnable the whole user interface will be blocked for the duration of the sleep so **do not do this**.

Instead of the `sleep` you can use

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000, runnable);
```

to schedule a new runnable to be run 1000 milliseconds later.

Comment: The problem is timerExec perform Runnable after given number of milliseconds from now, which makes creating of loopped tasks too complex. I seek for behavior simular to classic thread programming used in swing, but with SWT features.

Comment: Sorry but for SWT you have to do things like this.